# Fantasy series about a girl who lived in a village and there was a festival where they dance around a maypole

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, magic

About 4 years ago, I wasn't into reading but my husband told me to read this book so I did and I loved it. Now I'm into reading and can't remember the title to save my life! He can't remember either and it's driving us crazy. I really want to read it again and I believe it's a series so I want to continue it as well. These details could very well be from one or two of the books in the series, I read the ebooks so I don't know if it was multiple or not. Here are the very random details we remember:

- The main girl lived in a village and there was a festival where they dance around a maypole (IDK why this is what I remember)
- I also remember there was something about apples... like she loved them and was descriptive about apples
- There was a forest nearby that she was running through to get away from an army(?)
- There was something about a big hill too
- There was magic and I believe portals
- She traveled to a castle
- There was a romance element to it but I don't remember how much that played into the story

Comment: Where did he get the book from?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?